# Circuit understanding help

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, circuit-design, voltage

I am working on analyzing the following circuit. Could someone explain why there is such a big drop of voltage, from 4.24 KV to 0.707 KV? I am trying to figure out why the current is higher through Rf compared to R3, as this represents part of the vascular system and current through Rf should be really small. [image: Simple CSF Circuit]

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange. Could you share any information about where you came across this circuit? More context would be allow us to help you better.

Comment: Compare the voltages of the sources: The DC source has voltage way greater than both AC/sine ones. To simplify the analysis, "remove" both, and the capacitors. Both diodes are *forward biased", and have an effect similar to a closed switch or just a piece of wire: replace each with a wire. Do the results look familiar, can you see why the current through Rf is higher than that through R3?

Comment: Are the capacitors really 0.1 Farads (100,000 uF)? For 16 kV, those capacitors would be really huge!

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the circuit for DC. For now, ignore the AC sources and only look at the DC sources. Another assumption is the diode forward drop is zero to simplify the analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm80Mb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It becomes obvious that the DC current flowing through Rf+Ro will be 1.0417 times more than the current flowing through R3+R4. This agrees with the simulation.

If this is not what you expect, perhaps you drew the schematic wrong.